# How to parse shell values into mongoexport

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell

I am working on a shell script that will execute mongoexport and upload it to a S3 bucket.
The goal is to extract date as a readable JSON format on data that is 45 days old.The script will run everyday as a crontab.

So basically the purpose is to archive data older than 45 days

Normal queries work intended but when I try to use variables it results an error.

### The code regular format is as the following:

```
firstdate="$(date -v-46d +%Y-%m-%d)"
afterdate="$(date -v-45d +%Y-%m-%d)"
backup_name=gamebook
colname=test1

mongoexport --uri mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@gamebookserver.tvdmx.mongodb.net/$dbname
--collection $colname --query '{"gameDate": {"$gte": {"$date": "2020-09-04T00:00:00:000Z"}, "$lte": {"$date": "2020-09-05T00:00:00.000Z"}}}' --out $backup_name;
```

The previous code works but I want to make it more dynamic in the dates so I tried the code as shown below:

```
firstdate="$(date -v-46d +%Y-%m-%d)"
afterdate="$(date -v-45d +%Y-%m-%d)"
backup_name=gamebook
colname=test1

mongoexport --uri mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@gamebookserver.tvdmx.mongodb.net/$dbname
--collection $colname --query '{"gameDate": {"$gte": {"$date": "$firstdateT00:00:00:000Z"}, "$lte": {"$date": "$afterdateT00:00:00.000Z"}}}' --out $backup_name;
```

This results in the error:

> 2020-10-20T15:36:13.881+0700  query '[123 34 103 97 109 101 68 97 116 101 34 58 32 123 34 36 103 116 101 34 58 32 123 34 36 100 97 116 101 34 58 32 36 102 105 114 115 116 100 97 116 101 84 48 48 58 48 48 58 48 48 58 48 48 48 90 125 44 32 34 36 108 116 101 34 58 32 123 34 36 100 97 116 101 34 58 32 34 36 97 102 116 101 114 100 97 116 101 84 48 48 58 48 48 58 48 48 46 48 48 48 90 34 125 125 125]' is not valid JSON: invalid character '$' looking for beginning of value
> 2020-10-20T15:36:13.881+0700    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information

I've read in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/program/mongoexport/) and it says:

> You must enclose the query document in single quotes ('{ ... }') to ensure that it does not interact with your shell environment.

So my overall question is that is there a way to use values in the shell environment and parse them into the query section?

Or is there a better way that might get me the same result?

I'm still new to mongodb in general so any advise would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always put together a string by combining interpolating and non-interpolating parts:

For instance,

```
--query '{"gameDate": {"$gte": {"'"$date"'": "'"$firstdate"'T00:00:00:000Z"}, "$lte": {"$date": "$afterdateT00:00:00.000Z"}}}'
```

would interpolate the first occurance of `date` and the shell variable `firstdate`, but would passs the rest  literally to mongoexport (I've picked two variables for demonstration, because I don't understand from your question, which ones you want to expand and which one you don't want to). Basically, a

```
'$AAAA'"$BBBB"'$CCCCC'
```

is in effect a single string, but the $BBBB part would undergo parameter expansion. Hence, if

```
BBBB=foo
```

you would get the literal string *$AAAAfoo$CCCCC* out of this.

Since this become tedious to work, an alternative approach is to enclose everything into double-quotes, which means all parameters are expanded, and manually escape those parts which you don't want to expand. You could write the last example also as

```
"\$AAAA$BBBB\$CCCCC"
```

Comment: Thanks!!, 
I tried this and also used the 'queryfile' flag to help filter my dates into the query section.